# WinDbg Preview search is not returning results

Tags: windows, malware, memory, windbg, unpacking

I am attempting to manually unpack a malware sample. I am using the new WinDbg Preview (only thing that is available to download now). After letting the malware call VirtualAlloc I am trying to search the memory now but I am getting 0 results. I have been on Google and Microsoft docs about the range operator trying to get this to work but I cant get it to find anything. I am on a Windows 11 vm.

`s -a 0 L?4ffffff "This Program"`

Comment: Try few other variations like s -sa to search all ascii strings  s -su for all unicode  or just try searching for hex  like s ..... 0x(T)....